# Error in the Online generated Wrapper class from Json

Tags: json, wrapper-class

I have generated the wrapper class from Json2Apex admin booster.

Iam getting some error which I can understand but unable to fix it.

[image]

Please find the code.

```
//
//Generated by AdminBooster
//

public class HealthwiseWrapper{
    public Integer status;  //200
    public cls_versioning versioning;
    public cls_links links;
    public String schema;   //https://content.healthwise.net/v1/spec/schema.healthwise.api.item.json
    public cls_data data;
    class cls_versioning {
        **public String X-HW-Version;   //1**
    }
    class cls_links {
        public String self;
        public cls_localizations localizations;
        public cls_metadata metadata;
    }
    class cls_localizations {
        public String en_us;    
        public String es_us;
    }
    class cls_metadata {
        public String en_us;
        public String es_us;
    }
    class cls_data {
        public String id;   //tb1488
        public String version;  //11.3
        public String hash; //-1293733940
        public String certifiedDate;    //2016-11-15
        public String lang; //en-us
        public String docType;  //caresupport
        public String type; //caresupport
        public cls_resources resources;
        public cls_title title;
        **public cls_abstract abstract;**
        public cls_legal legal;
        public cls_credits credits;
        public String pageTemplate;
        public cls_topics[] topics;
    }
    class cls_resources {
        public cls_css[] css;
        public cls_javascript[] javascript;
        public String inline;   //
          **if (!window.org) var org = { healthwise: {'application':{}} };**
          else if (!window.org.healthwise) org['healthwise'] = {'application':{}};
          org.healthwise.config = { 
              root: 'https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/',
              locale: 'en-us',
              version: '11.3',
              isoshg: false
              };
      org.healthwise.document = {};
        org.healthwise.document.id = 'tb1488';
          org.healthwise.document.section = '';
          org.healthwise.document.healthwise = true;
          org.healthwise.document.title = 'Heart Failure'; org.healthwise.document.family = 'kb';
          org.healthwise.document.doctype = 'CareSupport'; 
          org.healthwise.document.pagetype = 'content'; 

    }
    class cls_css {
        public String target;   //https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/inc/style/main.css
    }
    class cls_javascript {
        public String target;   //https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/inc/control/healthwise.js
    }
    class cls_title {
        public String consumer; //Heart Failure
        public String englishConsumer;  //Heart Failure
    }
    class cls_abstract {
        public String consumer; 
        public String clinical; 
    }
    class cls_legal {
        public String logo; 
        public String disclaimer;   
        public String termsOfUseUrl;    
        public String privacyPolicyUrl; 
        public String moreInformationUrl;   //https://www.healthwise.org
        public String toLearnMoreHtml;  //To learn more about Healthwise, visit <a href="https://www.healthwise.org">Healthwise.org</a>.
        public String yourUseOfThisInformationHtml; 
    }
    class cls_credits {
        public cls_author author;
        public cls_primaryReviewers[] primaryReviewers;
        public cls_secondaryReviewers[] secondaryReviewers;
    }
    class cls_author {
        public String name; //Healthwise Staff 
    }
    class cls_primaryReviewers {
        public String name; //Adam Husney, MD - Family Medicine
        public String profileId;    //ua13981
        public String href; //https://content.healthwise.net/articles/ua13981/en-us?ContentVersion=11.3
    }
    class cls_secondaryReviewers {
        public String name; //Rakesh K. Pai, MD, FACC - Cardiology, Electrophysiology
        public String profileId;    //abl2729
        public String href; //https://content.healthwise.net/articles/abl2729/en-us?ContentVersion=11.3
    }
    class cls_topics {
        public String id;   //tb1488-sec
        public String lang; //en-us
        public String type; //HwNavigationSection
        public boolean navigable;
        public String html; 
    }
    public static HealthwiseWrapper parse(String json){
        return (HealthwiseWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, HealthwiseWrapper.class);
    }

    static testMethod void testParse() {
        String json=        '{"status":200,"versioning":{"X-HW-Version":"1"},"links":{"self":"https://content.healthwise.net/v1/articles/tb1488/en-us","localizations":{"en-us":"https://content.healthwise.net/articles/tb1488/en-us","es-us":"https://content.healthwise.net/articles/tb1488/es-us"},"metadata":{"en-us":"https://content.healthwise.net/metadata/tb1488/en-us","es-us":"https://content.healthwise.net/metadata/tb1488/es-us"}},"schema":"https://content.healthwise.net/v1/spec/schema.healthwise.api.item.json","data":{"id":"tb1488","version":"11.3","hash":"-1293733940","certifiedDate":"2016-11-15","lang":"en-us","docType":"caresupport","type":"caresupport","resources":{"css":[{"target":"https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/inc/style/main.css"},{"target":"https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/inc/style/main_ie8.css"},{"target":"https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/inc/style/print.css","media":"print"}],"javascript":[{"target":"https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/inc/control/healthwise.js"}],"inline":"\n          if (!window.org) var org = { healthwise: {\u0027application\u0027:{}} };\n          else if (!window.org.healthwise) org[\u0022healthwise\u0022] = {\u0027application\u0027:{}};\n          org.healthwise.config = { \n              root: \u0027https://assetpool.healthwise.net/11.3/common/desktop/alpine.api/\u0027,\n              locale: \u0027en-us\u0027,\n              version: \u002711.3\u0027,\n              isoshg: false\n          \n          };\n      org.healthwise.document = {};\n        org.healthwise.document.id = \u0022tb1488\u0022;\n          org.healthwise.document.section = \u0022\u0022;\n          org.healthwise.document.healthwise = true;\n          org.healthwise.document.title = \u0022Heart Failure\u0022; org.healthwise.document.family = \u0022kb\u0022;\n          org.healthwise.document.doctype = \u0022CareSupport\u0022; \n          org.healthwise.document.pagetype = \u0022content\u0022; \n          "},"title":{"consumer":"Heart Failure","englishConsumer":"Heart Failure"},"abstract":{"consumer":"There are many steps you can take to feel better and improve your health if you have heart failure. Medicine and lifestyle changes can slow heart failure in some people. Learning all you can about your condition can help you get the best results from your treatment.","clinical":"There are many steps you can take to feel better and improve your health if you have heart failure. Medicine and lifestyle changes can slow heart failure in some people. Learning all you can about your condition can help you get the best results from your treatment."},"legal":{"logo":"\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwLogo\u0022\u003e\u003ca data-hwid=\u0022support-abouthw\u0022 href=\u0022document/support-abouthw/support-abouthw-about\u0022 data-document-type=\u0022Support\u0022 data-document-href=\u0022support-abouthw\u0022 data-section-href=\u0022support-abouthw-about\u0022 data-articleId=\u0022support-abouthw\u0022 data-topicId=\u0022support-abouthw-about\u0022\u003e\u003cimg width=\u0022112\u0022 height=\u002246\u0022 class=\u0022HwNoHcMode\u0022 alt=\u0022Click here to learn about Healthwise\u0022 src=\u0022https://content.healthwise.net/resources/11.3/en-us/media/interface/hwlogo.png\u0022 data-resource-path=\u0022media/interface/hwlogo.png\u0022 /\u003e\u003cimg width=\u0022112\u0022 height=\u002246\u0022 class=\u0022HwHcMode\u0022 alt=\u0022Click here to learn about Healthwise\u0022 src=\u0022https://content.healthwise.net/resources/11.3/en-us/media/interface/hwlogo_hc.png\u0022 data-resource-path=\u0022media/interface/hwlogo_hc.png\u0022 /\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","disclaimer":"\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwDisclaimer\u0022\u003e\u003cp\u003e©2007-2017 Healthwise, Incorporated. Healthwise disclaims any liability for use of this information, which does not replace medical advice.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","termsOfUseUrl":"https://www.healthwise.org/specialpages/legal/terms.aspx","privacyPolicyUrl":"https://www.healthwise.org/specialpages/legal/privacy.aspx","moreInformationUrl":"https://www.healthwise.org","toLearnMoreHtml":"To learn more about Healthwise, visit \u003ca href=\u0022https://www.healthwise.org\u0022\u003eHealthwise.org\u003c/a\u003e.","yourUseOfThisInformationHtml":"Your use of this information means that you agree to the \u003ca href=\u0022https://www.healthwise.org/specialpages/legal/terms.aspx\u0022\u003eTerms of Use\u003c/a\u003e and \u003ca href=\u0022https://www.healthwise.org/specialpages/legal/privacy.aspx\u0022\u003ePrivacy Policy\u003c/a\u003e."},"credits":{"author":{"name":"Healthwise Staff "},"primaryReviewers":[{"name":"Adam Husney, MD - Family Medicine","profileId":"ua13981","href":"https://content.healthwise.net/articles/ua13981/en-us?ContentVersion=11.3"},{"name":"E. Gregory Thompson, MD - Internal Medicine","profileId":"zx1834","href":"https://content.healthwise.net/articles/zx1834/en-us?ContentVersion=11.3"},{"name":"Martin J. Gabica, MD - Family Medicine","profileId":"ts1200","href":"https://content.healthwise.net/articles/ts1200/en-us?ContentVersion=11.3"}],"secondaryReviewers":[{"name":"Rakesh K. Pai, MD, FACC - Cardiology, Electrophysiology","profileId":"abl2729","href":"https://content.healthwise.net/articles/abl2729/en-us?ContentVersion=11.3"}]},"pageTemplate":"\u003carticle\u003e\u003cdiv role=\u0022main\u0022 id=\u0022HwContentWrapper\u0022 class=\u0022HwTypeCareSupport HwContentWrapper HwElement\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCustom\u0022 id=\u0022HwCustomContentTop\u0022\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwContentHeader\u0022\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003ca name=\u0022top\u0022 id=\u0022Hwtop\u0022\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022HwAccessibilityText\u0022\u003eTop of the page\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwContentTitle\u0022\u003e\u003ch1 id=\u0022HwContentTitle\u0022\u003eHeart Failure\u003c/h1\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwContent\u0022 /\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCustom\u0022 id=\u0022HwCustomContentBottom\u0022\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwContentNavigation HwContentNavigationNoSections\u0022\u003e\u003cul\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwContentNavigationNone\u0022\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwContentNavigationTop\u0022\u003e\u003ca href=\u0022#top\u0022\u003eTop of Page\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwContentNavigationNone\u0022\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwContentInformation HwContentInformationNoSections\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwLastUpdated\u0022\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoLabel\u0022\u003eCurrent as of: \u003c/span\u003eNovember 15, 2016\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCredits\u0022\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoLabel\u0022\u003eAuthor: \u003c/span\u003e\u003ca data-hwid=\u0022support-abouthw\u0022 href=\u0022document/support-abouthw/content-team\u0022 data-document-type=\u0022Support\u0022 data-document-href=\u0022support-abouthw\u0022 data-section-href=\u0022content-team\u0022\u003eHealthwise Staff \u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoLabel\u0022\u003eMedical Review: \u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoName\u0022\u003e\u003ca data-hwid=\u0022ua13981\u0022 href=\u0022document/ua13981/ua13981-Intro\u0022 data-document-type=\u0022Profile\u0022 data-document-href=\u0022ua13981\u0022 data-section-href=\u0022ua13981-Intro\u0022\u003eAdam Husney, MD - Family Medicine\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e \u0026amp; \u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoName\u0022\u003e\u003ca data-hwid=\u0022zx1834\u0022 href=\u0022document/zx1834/zx1834-Intro\u0022 data-document-type=\u0022Profile\u0022 data-document-href=\u0022zx1834\u0022 data-section-href=\u0022zx1834-Intro\u0022\u003eE. Gregory Thompson, MD - Internal Medicine\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e \u0026amp; \u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoName\u0022\u003e\u003ca data-hwid=\u0022ts1200\u0022 href=\u0022document/ts1200/ts1200-Intro\u0022 data-document-type=\u0022Profile\u0022 data-document-href=\u0022ts1200\u0022 data-section-href=\u0022ts1200-Intro\u0022\u003eMartin J. Gabica, MD - Family Medicine\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e \u0026amp; \u003cspan class=\u0022HwInfoName\u0022\u003e\u003ca data-hwid=\u0022abl2729\u0022 href=\u0022document/abl2729/abl2729-Intro\u0022 data-document-type=\u0022Profile\u0022 data-document-href=\u0022abl2729\u0022 data-section-href=\u0022abl2729-Intro\u0022\u003eRakesh K. Pai, MD, FACC - Cardiology, Electrophysiology\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/article\u003e","topics":[{"id":"tb1488-sec","lang":"en-us","type":"HwNavigationSection","navigable":true,"html":"\u003csection\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwNavigationSection\u0022 id=\u0022tb1488-sec\u0022\u003e\u003ca name=\u0022tb1488-sec\u0022 data-articleId=\u0022\u0022 data-topicId=\u0022\u0022\u003e \u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspNewspaperLayout\u0022\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspTopicImage\u0022\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0022\u0022 height=\u0022217\u0022 src=\u0022https://content.healthwise.net/resources/11.3/en-us/media/medical/hw/tb1488_csp.jpg\u0022 width=\u0022227\u0022 class=\u0022HwCspImage\u0022 data-resource-path=\u0022media/medical/hw/tb1488_csp.jpg\u0022 /\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022e7138977\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00229f657b34\u0022\u003eThere are many steps you can take to feel better and improve your health if you have heart failure. Medicine and lifestyle changes can slow heart failure in some people.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022026854e4\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022c7a20263\u0022\u003eLearning all you can about your condition can help you get the best results from your treatment.\u003c/p\u003e\u003ch3 class=\u0022HwCspSubtitle\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u00226defc419\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00220db3b90e\u0022\u003eWhat is heart failure and what causes it?\u003c/h3\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u002252fad0b9\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00229818ebdd\u0022\u003eHeart failure occurs when your heart does not pump as much blood as your body needs. Failure does not mean that the heart has stopped pumping. It means it is not pumping as well as it should.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022461bc2ba\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022b30506bd\u0022\u003e Anything that damages the heart and its ability to pump can lead to heart failure. This includes coronary artery disease, heart attack, high blood pressure, and heart valve problems.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u002248054229\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022a1a125d3\u0022\u003eYou may not know you have heart failure until you have had it for years. This is because your heart can make up for not being able to pump well by getting bigger and beating faster. But it can only do this to a certain point.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022eb5b463c\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022c59cfd3c\u0022\u003eIn time, your heart gets worn out. You have symptoms, such as feeling weak, lightheaded, and very tired. Fluid builds up in your lungs and other parts of your body. This causes you to be short of breath and have swelling in your body.\u003c/p\u003e\u003ch3 class=\u0022HwCspSubtitle\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022ab190622\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00223faef86c\u0022\u003eWhat are the types of heart failure?\u003c/h3\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022012a8adf\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022304a5069\u0022\u003eAsk your doctor what type of heart failure you have. Most people get heart failure because of a problem with the heart\u0027s left lower chamber (ventricle).\u003c/p\u003e\u003cul data-fingerprint=\u00220e90f06f\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022cf1041f7\u0022\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eWhen the left ventricle cannot pump well, it is called \u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eheart failure with reduced ejection fraction\u003c/strong\u003e, or systolic heart failure.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eWhen the left ventricle cannot fill properly, it is called \u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eheart failure with preserved ejection fraction\u003c/strong\u003e, or diastolic heart failure. The ventricle pumps well, but it pumps out less blood than normal.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003ch3 class=\u0022HwCspSubtitle\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u00225e1c2848\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00225c81d17c\u0022\u003eWhat increases your risk for heart failure?\u003c/h3\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u00228459ab50\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u002242026243\u0022\u003eHeart failure is generally caused by another disease, such as CAD, heart attack, and high blood pressure. Anything that increases your risk for getting one of those diseases also adds to your risk, or is a risk factor, for heart failure. For example, diabetes increases your chance of having CAD, so it is also a risk factor for heart failure.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022bc5e2b7d\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022765df570\u0022\u003e Some risk factors exist because of who you are. Some result from your lifestyle choices. Others come from your environment. Some risks that you cannot control include:\u003c/p\u003e\u003cul data-fingerprint=\u0022a8bb6cde\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00223ba1cbe9\u0022\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eYour age. The risk of developing heart failure rises sharply as you age.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eYour sex. Overall, men are at a higher risk for heart failure than women. But this difference narrows as women get older.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eYour family history. If any of your close relatives have or had heart failure, you may have inherited a risk for heart failure.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022390cead2\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u0022545e4fed\u0022\u003eYou may be able to control many things that increase your risk for heart failure. Examples include:\u003c/p\u003e\u003cul data-fingerprint=\u00226766377a\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00229f008f09\u0022\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eUsing tobacco. Smoking increases your risk of heart disease.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e Drinking large amounts of alcohol, which can raise your blood pressure, trigger uneven heartbeats, and damage your heart muscle.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003eNot getting enough physical activity. Lack of exercise can increase your risk of high blood pressure, high cholesterol, high blood sugar levels, blood clots, obesity, and stress.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003ePoor eating habits, which can cause obesity and lead to high blood pressure, diabetes, and high cholesterol.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u002210ccb479\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u002274378432\u0022\u003eHaving a risk factor does not mean that you will develop heart disease. Even if you have no risk factors, you still may develop heart failure.\u003c/p\u003e\u003ch3 class=\u0022HwCspSubtitle\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u00224b137b5a\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u002262efeb6d\u0022\u003eHow is heart failure treated?\u003c/h3\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u002246f664ef\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00222812079d\u0022\u003eYour doctor\u0027s goal is to relieve your symptoms and prevent more heart damage. Your doctor will also need to treat the problem that caused your heart failure. You will probably take several medicines to reduce blood pressure and fluid buildup and decrease your heart\u0027s workload.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022417bfe67\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u002258f21619\u0022\u003eIt is very important to take your medicines exactly as your doctor tells you to and to keep taking them. If you have any problems with the medicines, tell your doctor. You may be able to take different ones to get the same benefit.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u002257d37f70\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00227af3af59\u0022\u003eYour doctor will also recommend some lifestyle changes. Taking these steps can help you feel better and might help slow the progression of heart failure:\u003c/p\u003e\u003cul data-fingerprint=\u002269d6ff61\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00220bcb405b\u0022\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eEat less sodium\u003c/strong\u003e. This helps keep fluid from building up. It may help you feel better.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eGet regular exercise\u003c/strong\u003e, which will help keep your heart healthy.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eLose weight\u003c/strong\u003e if you are overweight. Even small changes can make a difference.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eStop smoking\u003c/strong\u003e.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eLimit alcohol\u003c/strong\u003e. Ask your doctor how much, if any, is safe.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eControl your blood pressure\u003c/strong\u003e. Exercise, limit alcohol, and control stress to help keep your blood pressure in a healthy range. You may also need to take medicine.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli class=\u0022HwCspListItem\u0022\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspListText\u0022\u003e\u003cstrong class=\u0022HwCspBold\u0022\u003eWatch your fluid intake\u003c/strong\u003e if your doctor advises it.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u00226ac0ca3f\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u00222ffa2ae0\u0022\u003eAsk your doctor if a cardiac rehab program is right for you. Rehab can give you education and support that help you learn self-care and build new healthy habits, such as exercise.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0022HwCspImportant\u0022\u003e\u003cp class=\u0022HwCspParagraph\u0022 data-fingerprint=\u0022f0f98c37\u0022 data-fingerprint-exact=\u002253bc2e04\u0022\u003eHeart failure often gets worse over time and requires more treatment to manage symptoms and control complications. Take your medicines as prescribed, make some lifestyle changes, and work closely with your doctor. These give you the best chance to control heart failure and prevent complications.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/section\u003e"}]}}';
        HealthwiseWrapper obj = parse(json);
        System.assert(obj != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have marked the error line with double asterix in the code. **  **

Answer (score 0):

Because `abstract` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm), you cannot declare it as an identifier name.

Comment: Can please advise what would be the error on line number 47  if (!window.org) var org = { healthwise: {'application':{}} };